# How to calculate mean by group when there are missing combination

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set with two keys (`ID` and `Cells`), for multiple Dates. 
I want to calculate the average of `MM` in a monthly basis. The problem is that some Dates are missing from some `ID`-`Cells` combination, but I can use one `MM` from each day, so this is not a problem.

What I do is create a new data table with the unique dates, calculate the average of `MM`, then merge it with the original data table and then removing the duplicate columns.

This is not efficient, obviously. Is there an other way to do it?

Reproducible example:

```
sapply(c('data.table', 'lubridate'), require, character.only = TRUE)

DT <- fread('DATE, ID, Cells, MM
2000-01-01, 1, 1,  100
2000-01-02, 1, 2,  200
2000-01-03, 1, 3,  300 
2000-01-01, 2, 10, 100
2000-01-02, 2, 20, 200
2000-01-03, 2, 30, 300
2000-01-04, 2, 40, 400
2000-02-01, 1, 1,  500
2000-02-02, 1, 2,  600 
2000-02-04, 1, 4,  800
2000-02-01, 2, 10, 500 
2000-02-03, 2, 30, 700
2000-02-04, 2, 40, 800')

DT[, date := as.Date(DATE, format = '%Y-%m-%d')]
DT[, c('Year', 'Month', 'Day') := .(year(date), 
                              month(date), day(date))]

setkey(DT, DATE)
DT.MM <- DT[which(!duplicated(DT))]

setkey(DT.MM, DATE)
DT.MM[, AverageMM := mean(MM), by = .(Year, Month)]

DT <- DT[DT.MM]

DT[, c('i.ID', 'i.Cells', 'i.date', 'i.Year', 'i.Month', 'i.Day') := NULL]
# > DT # This is what I want to get back
#          DATE ID Cells  MM       date Year Month Day AverageMM
# 1: 2000-01-01  1     1 100 2000-01-01 2000     1   1       250
# 2: 2000-01-01  2    10 100 2000-01-01 2000     1   1       250
# 3: 2000-01-02  1     2 200 2000-01-02 2000     1   2       250
# 4: 2000-01-02  2    20 200 2000-01-02 2000     1   2       250
# 5: 2000-01-03  1     3 300 2000-01-03 2000     1   3       250
# 6: 2000-01-03  2    30 300 2000-01-03 2000     1   3       250
# 7: 2000-01-04  2    40 400 2000-01-04 2000     1   4       250
# 8: 2000-02-01  1     1 500 2000-02-01 2000     2   1       650
# 9: 2000-02-01  2    10 500 2000-02-01 2000     2   1       650
#10: 2000-02-02  1     2 600 2000-02-02 2000     2   2       650
#11: 2000-02-03  2    30 700 2000-02-03 2000     2   3       650
#12: 2000-02-04  1     4 800 2000-02-04 2000     2   4       650
#13: 2000-02-04  2    40 800 2000-02-04 2000     2   4       650
```

Comment: Why not just `DT[, AverageMM := mean(MM), .(Year, Month)]`?

Comment: @Jaap, because I get a different AverageMM this way. For example, I get `228.57` for January, while I want to get 250. This happens because "your" mean (which is more normal than what I want) is calculated based on the existing observations, while I want to account for missing observations. That is, I want to hypothesize that MM exists for some particular day if it is missing.

Comment: How do you come at the values of `250` and `650`? See my answer for a solution which takes missing observations into account. However, i get different values.

Comment: `DT.MM <- DT[which(!duplicated(DT))]` <- I don't get the reason behind this line as you're ignoring certain ID entries to calculate the average after. duplicated on a data.table will filter on the key if present, and you did set the key as being the DATE column....

Comment: Shouldn't you look at missing `DATE`/`ID` combinations instead of only looking at missing dates?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is using a cross-join on `DATE` and `ID` as reference in `i` to add the missing `DATE`/`ID` combinations and then calculate the mean:

```
DT[CJ(DATE, ID, unique = TRUE), on=c(DATE="V1", ID="V2")
   ][, AverageMM := sum(MM, na.rm = TRUE)/.N, by = .(year(DATE), month(DATE))][]
```

which gives:

```
          DATE ID Cells  MM Year Month Day AverageMM
 1: 2000-01-01  1     1 100 2000     1   1     200.0
 2: 2000-01-01  2    10 100 2000     1   1     200.0
 3: 2000-01-02  1     2 200 2000     1   2     200.0
 4: 2000-01-02  2    20 200 2000     1   2     200.0
 5: 2000-01-03  1     3 300 2000     1   3     200.0
 6: 2000-01-03  2    30 300 2000     1   3     200.0
 7: 2000-01-04  1    NA  NA   NA    NA  NA     200.0
 8: 2000-01-04  2    40 400 2000     1   4     200.0
 9: 2000-02-01  1     1 500 2000     2   1     487.5
10: 2000-02-01  2    10 500 2000     2   1     487.5
11: 2000-02-02  1     2 600 2000     2   2     487.5
12: 2000-02-02  2    NA  NA   NA    NA  NA     487.5
13: 2000-02-03  1    NA  NA   NA    NA  NA     487.5
14: 2000-02-03  2    30 700 2000     2   3     487.5
15: 2000-02-04  1     4 800 2000     2   4     487.5
16: 2000-02-04  2    40 800 2000     2   4     487.5
```

Another possibility is to add the missing `DATE`/`ID` combinations with the `complete` function from the *tidyr* package:

```
library(tidyr)
setDT(complete(DT,DATE,ID))[, AverageMM := sum(MM, na.rm = TRUE)/.N, by = .(year(DATE), month(DATE))][]
```

which will give you the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do...

```
DT[, aveMM := weighted.mean(MM, !duplicated(DATE)), by=.(year(DATE), month(DATE))]
```

which gives

```
          DATE ID Cells  MM AveMM
 1: 2000-01-01  1     1 100   250
 2: 2000-01-02  1     2 200   250
 3: 2000-01-03  1     3 300   250
 4: 2000-01-01  2    10 100   250
 5: 2000-01-02  2    20 200   250
 6: 2000-01-03  2    30 300   250
 7: 2000-01-04  2    40 400   250
 8: 2000-02-01  1     1 500   650
 9: 2000-02-02  1     2 600   650
10: 2000-02-04  1     4 800   650
11: 2000-02-01  2    10 500   650
12: 2000-02-03  2    30 700   650
13: 2000-02-04  2    40 800   650
```

This assigns a weight of zero to duplicated days.

---

To extend to functions other than `mean`, an approach like this works:

```
DT[, AveMM := mean(tapply(MM, DATE, head, 1)), by=.(year(DATE), month(DATE))]
```

However, it's not very data.table-ish.